# How to index a list with a TensorFlow tensor?

Tags: python, list, indexing, tensorflow

Assume a list with non concatenable objects which needs to be accessed via a look up table. So the list index will be a tensor object but this is not possible.

```
 tf_look_up = tf.constant(np.array([3, 2, 1, 0, 4]))
 index = tf.constant(2)
 list = [0,1,2,3,4]

 target = list[tf_look_up[index]]
```

This will bring out the following error message.

```
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor
```

Is the a way/workaround to index lists with tensors?

Comment: Use sess.run to convert tensor to numpy first

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov what if the list is produced dynamically, e.g. the states that a RNN produces. Any way list dynamic indexing would work?

Comment: maybe `tf.gather` like in @soloice answer?

Answer (score 14):

`tf.gather` is designed for this purpose.

Simply run `tf.gather(list, tf_look_up[index])`, you'll get what you want.

Comment: What if the list is something like `[[1], [2, 3], [4]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow actually has support for a `HashTable`.  See the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/HashTable) for more details.

Here, what you could do is the following:

```
table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(
    tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(tf_look_up, list), -1)
```

Then just get the desired input by running

```
target = table.lookup(index)
```

Note that `-1` is the default value if the key is not found.  You may have to add `key_dtype` and `value_dtype` to the constructor depending on the configuration of your tensors.