# Indexing Python lists that cannot convert into tensors

Tags: tensorflow

How do you index a Python list in TensorFlow if the list's elements are functions?

I've read @soloice's answer at [How to index a list with a Tensorflow tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187181/how-to-index-a-list-with-a-tensorflow-tensor). However, it assumes that the list can be converted into a tensor.

If I have a list L of functions, indexing methods like `tf.gather(L,index)` don't work because `L` cannot be converted into a tensor.